# Method to find out the amount of solvent replaced by another solvent

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water, solvents, precipitation

So I am performing a relatively simple coprecipitation experiment to synthesize ceramics. All my precursors are in aqueous solutions. But due to the high surface tension of water, drying the water is affecting my surface area and porosity. So I  have introduced a solvent washing step, where I try to replace water by ethanol using ethanol washing, as the surface tension of ethanol is quite low.
So I am hoping that when I replace water by ethanol, the morphology of my particles will be improved.

I need to measure how much water has been effectively replaced by ethanol.CHN analysis is one way to it, but we don't have that in our lab.

Is there any other relatively simple way in which I can do this?

Thanks for assisting

Comment: Someone more into analytical chemistry could provide a better solution, but a dirty way comes to my mind: if only water and ethanol are present, you could use molecular sieves 3A as selective media for absorbing water (some testing or literature search might be needed, to check if the method is indeed appropriate). My idea: place your compound with a measured amount of vacuum-dried molecular sieves in a pressure-resistant, closed container under inert gas.

Comment: Heat the container in a oven for some time, and let it cool. Weight the molecular sieves, which will contain mainly (only?) water. Vacuum dry your compound, and weight it. The difference should represent the weight of ethanol.

Comment: @The_Vinz but my system contains a lot other compounds mainly metal nitrates and also ammonium carbonate as the base for precipitating all the metals hydroxides and carbonates down.